# Entity Framework won't update record after SaveChanges() with state=EntityState.Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to do a simple update with Entity Framework. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my update statement?

Everything goes smoothly - no error at runtime, however nothing gets changed in the database.

Here is my code I hope it helps

```
var cartItem = context.Carts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
cartItem.Quantity = quantity;
context.Entry(cartItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Carts.Attach(cartItem);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The problem was not a code mistake but rather a bug in entity framework itself, when there is an aspx page with the same name as one of the objects generated by the edmx on SaveChanges instead of taking the properties of the model for the current item the or/m takes the properties of the webpage and throws null reference exception because it can't find the right values for the query. Thank you for the assist and patience by the way.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're attaching the entity before to call `SaveChanges` method:

```
  var cartItem = context.Carts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
  cartItem.Quantity = quantity;

  context.SaveChanges();
```

Also if you haven't disabled EF change tracking then you don't need to change the `State` to `Modified`, EF will do the job for you. When you call `Attach` method you are setting the `State` property to `Unchanged`.

You can use `Attach` this way:

```
var cartItem= new Cart{id=id}; //Create an instance of your entity setting the key
context.Carts.Attach(cartItem);// Attach the entity to the context
cartItem.Quantity = quantity; //Set the property
//If you haven't disabled change tracking or proxy creation, then you don't need to change the State, EF will do it.
context.Entry(cartItem).State = EntityState.Modified;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If I try to save changes while the entity is not attached I get null reference exception on behalf of the context because there is no such entity there

Comment: null reference exception? I don't understand why, anyway I will post another solution using `Attach`

Comment: Well yes I found it strange as well that's why I've asked here

Comment: I have Proxy generation on false and lazy loading enabled, also there is one question wont var  cartItem= new Cart{id=id} set all other fields to null except quantity?I can't see how its updating the current selected record

Comment: Then you need to set the status to `Modified`. Answering you other question,  when you attach the entity you are repopulating the context with an entity that is known to already exist in the database, so if it hasn't been loaded yet, then it will be loaded when you call Attach. If the entity already exist in the context then that is the entity you are going to use.

Comment: I totally get that however without adding attach entity framework gives me null reference exception

Comment: It's difficult to me identify the issue with the info you're sharing

Comment: Well First I am taking a list of Cart, the list gets handled by the UI whenever a user clicks a button I have to take the clicked item increase its quantity by 1 and save it to the database...So I am sending ajax request retrieving the id of the item and the quantity that has to be set the rest is simple I need working update query to update the quantity of the selected product however its suppose to be simple according to the documentation first I need to set the context.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Modified then call context.SaveChanges() but there is that problem that if I don't have

Comment: context.Carts.Attach(entity) I get null reference exception and if I have it I don't get an exception but nothing gets saved and I get that its because attach creates new instance of the object but I can't get why I get exception if I don't have it.

Comment: Did you try with my second solution?

Comment: Yes it didn't work  I am getting this Attaching an entity of type 'PriTarikata.Cart' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified'